# Can you orderBy two fields in firebase?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using google Firestore as my database, I wanted to order my material table by two fields (name and date) so I can have it in alphabetical order + in the date it was created, however I got the following error:

[image]

This is my code with "acudiente" being the name of the user and "fecha" being the date of the order and "pedidos" being the collection.

```
useEffect(() => { 
    const usuariosRef = db.collectionGroup('pedidos')
    usuariosRef.orderBy("acudiente", "fecha").onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      const tempData = [];
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const data = doc.data();
        
        tempData.push(data);
        console.log(tempData)
      });
      setPedidos(tempData);
    })
   }, []);
```

Comment: Have you tried. -> `usuariosRef.orderBy("acudiente").orderBy("fecha").onSnapshot(....`

Comment: I doubt that will work didn't saw anything like that in the documentation as far as I'm aware orderBy is for single fields but I'm willing to give it a try

Comment: I don't use firebase, but I did see this in the docs -> https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/samples/firestore-query-order-multi#firestore_query_order_multi-nodejs

Comment: @ReactPotato Instead of doubting it, I recommend giving it a try. And when you get an error message, check carefully what is says as Firestore may be telling you to  create an index for the query - and that error message includes a link that takes you exactly to the page where you can do so, with all details already filled in.

Comment: well that was unexpected, hahaha it actually worked. Idk why they don't have that in their examples and have it completely separated in another section.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I did say I was gonna try it, took some time to create the index which is why I took a bit to reply